# vba copy certain range and paste as picture

Tags: vba, excel

Now I can copy the whole borders from Sheet1 to Sheet2 but my problem is I can't copy the specific range like last 10 columns value with the header. For example, when input new value at O column it will just copy and paste the from F to O with the headers.

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Select
Set startcell = Range("B2")
startcell.CurrentRegion.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

[image: example of image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyLastTenCols()
    'declaration of variables
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet, lastCol As Long
    Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    'here we determine last column to copy
    lastCol = sheet1.Cells(2, 2).End(xlToRight).Column
    'here, we union headers with last ten columns, then paste it to range
    'of appropriate size, starting in A1 cell
    Union(sheet1.Range("B2:B5"), sheet1.Range(sheet1.Cells(2, lastCol - 9), sheet1.Cells(5, lastCol))).Copy sheet2.Range("A1:K4")
End Sub
```

Comment: i am sry, it work but how to paste it as picture?i use .CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap it doesn't work

Comment: one last problem when click on sheet2(pasted sheet) and run ,it will show error"1004".but when i on sheet1 one run without selected column it will run as fine~tyty

Comment: why i must run the macros on sheet 1 then it will run fine,it i run macros at sheet2 i will pop up error 1004

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this task is something you are able to do manually (without VBA), that you now want to automate:

Use the **<kbd>Macro Recorder</kbd>** to **record the steps** that you take to accomplish this manually, then <kbd>**Edit**</kbd> the macro to view the VBA code, remove any extraneous sections, and you will be left with the code you're looking for.

This process can be used for any task that you know how to do manually (with Excel's) built-in features, but you want to automate.

This is how I learned the first half of what I know about VBA today. It's a good "cheater" way to get started in VBA.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code)
- MSDN : [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros)

Comment: While these are very good advices, they do not provide answer to the question I am afraid :)

Comment: It's explanation of exactly how the OP can solve the problem (and others), as opposed to rewarding a poorly researched question with "free custom coding".  (There's a [trend](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/836890/avg-q-a-average-scores-monthly-month-by-month-comparison-last-10-years#graph) that needs to be turned around.)

Answer (score 1):

you may be after this

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").CurrentRegion
        If .Columns.Count > 11 Then .Columns(2).Resize(.Columns.Count - 11).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        .CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").PasteSpecial
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it show error unable to get the currentregion property of the range class

Comment: Then your data are not as you showed in your question. I wrote my code as per data you showed. You own code is using CurrentRegion on Range B2...